# Partially visible rectangle detection opencv

Tags: opencv, detection

(*editing the question completely as i am trying a different approach*)

I am trying to find the corners of a plain paper sheet which can be partially obstructed.
I am using houghlines now to get the lines and then calculating their intersections, this approach is robust and gives good results even if the paper is partially obstructed.

Problems:

1) There are multiple intersection points very closeby, how do i merge them fast as i am displaying the results in realtime.

2) As there might be some points detected outside the paper (due to some noise of some other object) how do i get a polygon from the intersection points.

[image]

[image]

```
GaussianBlur(grayscaleMat, grayscaleMat, cvSize(11,11), 0);//change from median blur to gaussian for more accuracy of square detection

cv::Canny(grayscaleMat, grayscaleMat, 50, 150, 3);

cv::Mat color;
cv::cvtColor(grayscaleMat, color, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(grayscaleMat, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 0, 0 );

if(lines.size() == 0) {
    return image;
}
////////////////////////////////////
// Start geometery
//merge close lines
std::vector<cv::Vec2f> linesMerged = [ATOpenCVGeometery mergeCloseLines:lines];

//find intersections
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points = [ATOpenCVGeometery intersectionsBetweenLines:linesMerged];


for(int i = 0;i < linesMerged.size();i++) {
    [self drawLine:image vec2f:linesMerged[i] color:cv::Scalar(0,0,255)];
}

for(int i = 0;i < points.size();i++) {
    cv::circle(image, points[i], 4, cv::Scalar(255,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have, I think if you focus more on the edge of the paper instead of the corner, you will get more robust result.

Comment: added code and images